# Animation in viewDidAppear

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview

I have an image that I wish to animate after a view has appeared. I'm doing the following:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    CGRect folderFrame = self.folderImage.frame;

    folderFrame.origin.y += 250;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:250 animations:^{
        self.folderImage.frame = folderFrame;
    }];
}
```

But I can't see any animation. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is working, but moving 1 point per second, practically imperceptible. Try specifying a shorter duration for the animation.

Comment: Aha! I thought I was working with milliseconds for some reason. Rookie error. :)

Comment: Is there any specific reason why the same code (now with a sensible duration) wouldn't animate in viewWillDisappear as well?

Answer (score 3):

If this is the exact code you are using, then the problem might be that you have the animation set to take 250 seconds (about 4 minutes). Is it possible that it **is** animating, just very, very slowly?